# How to create this felt material effect?

Tags: materials

How can I achieve this felt material effect and overall render using Blender?

Image taken from https://www.instagram.com/p/ChCqNdquqaC/?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y=

[image: Microsoft design books]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this - it's really just a couple of Noise Textures, one stretched into almost vertical lines and then mixed together. I used these as the basis for a Bump Node. The key to the "Velvet" is the subsurface scattering (I set all 3 radius values to .2) the main value is .05. I used a colorramp to grab some of the tiny thin slices from the stretched noise texture to use as the basis for the little "Reflective bits", (metallic factor) using its inverse (basically) as the roughness.

Here is an example file for anyone curious - [image]

[image: Velvet]

Comment: can you attach the blend file? :)

Comment: Sure thing - I added it - it's a bit more upgraded than the previous, but pretty much the same.

Comment: My bad too, in the new file, take the result of the 2 black ColorRamp mix and add that 100% to the basecolor (will make the "shiny" bits silver, instead of multicolor/shade)